# PHP Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\poll\add.php on line 19 and 20

Tags: php, sql

I created a poll voting concept. I have an error in this code. How can i achieve that?

I got this code, it is not working because it is a voting concept, it divided by 100 to calculate the vote. I run in localhost it not divided by 100, it divided by 0. How can i solve this error?

> Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\poll\add.php on line 19
>
> Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\poll\add.php on line 20

```
<?php
$connect = @mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','poll');
$poll = $_POST['poll'];
if (isset($poll))
{
    $SQL="";
    if ($poll =="1")
    {
        $SQL = "UPDATE poll SET yes =yes+1 WHERE id = 1";
        }
        elseif ($poll =="0"){
            $SQL="UPDATE poll SET no =no + 1 WHERE id = 1";
        }
        $query = mysqli_query($connect,$SQL);
        if($query)
        {
            $retSQL = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM poll");
            $resarr = mysqli_fetch_array($retSQL);
            $yes = 100 * round($resarr['yes'] / ($resarr['no'] + $resarr['yes']),2);
            $no = 100 * round($resarr['no'] / ($resarr['yes'] + $resarr['no']),2);
            echo 'YES: '.$yes.'%';
            echo 'NO: '.$no.'%';                       
        }else{
            echo 'Bad';
        }

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You get this warnings when the expression `$resarr['no'] + $resarr['yes']` evaluates to `0`. This is the case when both values are zero, so there aren't any votes yet. Check beforehand if `$resarr['no'] + $resarr['yes']` evaluates to `0`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing the calculations in the database to begin with ~ it's not tested btw but looks like it should work ( famous last words )

```
$connect = @mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','poll');

if (isset( $_POST['poll'] ) ){

    $poll = $_POST['poll'];

    switch( $poll ){
        case 1:$sql='update `poll` set `yes`=`yes`+1 where `id` = 1';break;
        case 0:$sql='update poll set `no`=`no` + 1 where `id` = 1';break;
    }
    $result = mysqli_query( $connect, $sql );
    if( $result ){

        $sql='select 
            round( ( `yes`/ (`no` + `yes`) ), 2 ) as `yes`,
            round( ( `no` / (`yes` + `no`) ),2 ) as `no`
        from poll';

        $result=mysqli_query( $connect, $sql );
        if( $result ){
            while( $rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
                echo "yes: {$rs['yes']}\nNo: {$rs['no']}"
            }
        } else{
            echo 'Bad foo';
        }
    }
}



mysql> describe poll;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| yes   | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| no    | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from poll;
+----+-----+----+
| id | yes | no |
+----+-----+----+
|  1 |  32 | 26 |
+----+-----+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> select
        round( ( `yes`/ ( `no` + `yes` ) ), 2 ) as `yes`,
        round( ( `no` / ( `yes` + `no` ) ), 2 ) as `no`
        from poll;
+------+------+
| yes  | no   |
+------+------+
| 0.55 | 0.45 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

or, with formatted results

```
mysql> select 
            concat( round( round( ( `yes`/ ( `no` + `yes` ) ), 2 ) * 100,0),'%') as `yes`,
            concat( round( round( ( `no` / ( `yes` + `no` ) ), 2 ) * 100,0),'%') as `no`
        from poll;
+------+------+
| yes  | no   |
+------+------+
| 55%  | 45%  |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

i think , in your computation you should compress by parenthesis `()` to come up correct calculation

```
$yes = 100 * round(($resarr['yes'] / ($resarr['no'] + $resarr['yes'])),2);
$no = 100 * round(($resarr['no'] / ($resarr['yes'] + $resarr['no'])),2);
```

to remove php warnings use `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);`
anyway you can follow this [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)